# Surface integral over graph of a function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Q: Evaluate the surface integral  $\iint_S \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{S}$, where $\mathbf{F}(x,y,z)= 3x^2\mathbf{i}-2xy\mathbf{j}+8\mathbf{k}$, and $S$ is the graph of the function $z=f(x,y)=2x-y$ for $0\leq x\leq2$ and $0\leq y \leq2$.

Attempt: This question is from a previous years Vector Calculus exam. When attempting to solve, I had thought to parameterize the surface, and then use $\int_a^b \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{c}(t))\cdot \mathbf{c}'(t)\,dt$, $a \leq t \leq b$. In the solutions, they have  $$\iint_S \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{S} = \int_0^2\int_0^2  (-6x^2-2xy+8)\,dxdy= -8$$

I'm mostly looking for an explanation as to how they arrived at the expression inside the integral ($-6x^2-2xy+8$), any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The surface integral is better written as

$$\iint_S dS \, \hat{\mathbf{n}} \cdot \mathbf{F}$$

where $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$ is the unit surface normal.  For surfaces of the form $z=f(x,y)$, the unit normal is

$$\hat{\mathbf{n}} = \frac{\displaystyle\left(-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y},1\right)}{\displaystyle\sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)^2+1}}$$

Note that the normalizing factor in the denominator is exactly the stretching factor relating the surface area element to the differential $dx\,dy$:

$$dS = \sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)^2+1} \, dx\, dy$$

Now, $\partial f/\partial x = 2$ and $\partial f/\partial y = -1$, so that

$$\iint_S dS \, \hat{\mathbf{n}} \cdot \mathbf{F} = \int_0^2 dx \, \int_0^2 dy \, [-(2) \cdot (3 x^2) - (-1) \cdot (-2 x y) + (1)\cdot (8)] $$

which is the result you wanted to see.